# 10 rep missing intermittently from account overview

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

My reputation on SO is `3,895` and it has been ever since February 2nd, as https://stackoverflow.com/users/950430/dennis?tab=reputation shows:

[image: click to expand]

However, the account overview on the profile page, sometimes shows only `3,885`, as seen on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/170332/dennis:

[image: click to expand]

Additional information:

- I've noticed it once on MSO and twice on SU.
- http://stackoverflow.com did not show any changes on all three occasions.
- Opening the *view more* link below the 5 top accounts in a new tab and refreshing subsequently immediately fixed the offset.

Any ideas where my 10 rep goes when it's not home?

Comment: Your red lines **definitely** have to be bigger than that to hold in every last rep point.

Comment: Caching[.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @ChrisF: That's a very discrete looking period there[.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121716/10-rep-missing-intermittently-from-account-overview#comment322802_121716)

Comment: @animuson - I needed some more characters :)

Comment: @ChrisF: Not saying your wrong, but I don't get it. Why do I get the current rep for SU, but intermittently last week's rep for SO?

Comment: @Dennis - The value on your account page *is* cached. Now if there's something dodgy going on with the cache that would explain it. All I was trying to say was don't worry. The correct value is in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our network-level user cache had a hiccup.  You should be all fixed.

Also, here's my first (and hopefully only) attempt at using a meme:

[image]