# Bonus +100 applied to account with 200, but other accounts don't think so

Tags: support, reputation, association-bonus

My reputation on Stack Overflow is 200; so every account, including Stack Overflow gained the 100 point bonus. However, when I view my Stack Overflow account from, e.g. [SuperUser accounts tab](https://superuser.com/users/84220/sindikat?tab=accounts), it still shows 200, not 300.

It is definitely a bug.

Comment: It's called [caching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121741/167443).

Comment: I wonder if this has the same underlying cause as [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep#comment339507_125439) and its duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a caching issue. Given a certain amount of time the account list on Super User will show the correct amount of reputation for your Stack Overflow account.

Comment: @sindikat Your account tab on SU now shows 306 reputation for you SO.